# Is there chance to restore deleted column in ASPNETDB?

Tags: asp.net, sql, aspnetdb

I deleted "UserName" column in aspnet_Users (ASPNETDB) is there chanse to restore it? I can't just add that column it will change schema.

Comment: You need to restore from the database backup. Hopefully you have transaction log backups that will let you restore to a time pretty close to when you dropped this column.

Answer (score 1):

What adding the column it would be a schema change?

If you have a backup, restore it with another database name.
Add the column to your table and then update the column using join to the database table of the backup

Eg.

UPDATE a
SET a.UserName = b.UserName
FROM mydb1.dbo.table1 AS a
INNER JOIN mybackupdb1.dbo.table1 AS b
WHERE a.id = b.id